# Unable to generate a deck of cards in c++

Tags: c++

I am making a project where I simulate a poker game in C++.  Currently, the function I have appears to work whenever I go through it in debug mode in Visual Studio.  However, whenever I actually run the program, the console cursor just blinks and does not appear to execute past the initialization of the class.  If I go through in debug mode, it stops at some point during the generation of the cards.  I know the card generation is not random right now I removed that for simplicity.

`Card` class:

```
class Card
{
    public:
    string value;
    string suit;
    int ValToInt();
};
```

`Deck` class:

```
class Deck
{
public:
    int deckSize;
    Card deck[52];
    void RandCard(Card &card);
    Deck();
};
```

`RandCard` function:

```
void Deck::RandCard(Card &card)
{
    bool duplicateCard = false;
    Card tempCard;
    const string valueList[13] = { "A","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","J","Q","K" };
    const string suitList[4] = { "s", "c", "h", "d" };
    do {
        tempCard.value = valueList[rand() % 13];
        tempCard.suit = suitList[rand() % 4];

        for (int i = 0; i < deckSize; i++)
        {
            if ((deck[i].value == tempCard.value) && (deck[i].suit == tempCard.suit))
            {
                duplicateCard = true;
                break;
            }
        }
    } while (duplicateCard == true);
    card = tempCard;
}
```

Default constructor and how I am attempting to use the `RandCard` function:

```
Deck::Deck()
{
    deckSize = 0;
    Card emptyCard;
    emptyCard.value = "EMPTY";
    emptyCard.suit = "EMPTY";
    for (int i = 0; i < 52; i++)
    {
        RandCard(deck[i]);
        deckSize++;
    }
}
```

Thank you for any help.

Comment: show how this code gets run, where is the main?

Comment: Please post code that compiles and the least.  Next, push all 52 card objects into a container, call shuffle, then pop them back out to deal.  Your method generates 52 truly random cards, not an actual deck.

Comment: Once `duplicateCard` has somewhere become `true`,  it will never get `false` again. Then `while (duplicateCard == true)` will be an endless loop, right? Note that the `break` exits the inner `for`-loop, but not the `while`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to generate 52 cards mixed, your best bet is to generate 52 cards and use std::shuffle or std::random_shuffle. There is a reason behind this. Imagine the following scenario:

You have generated 51 cards and are about to generate the 52nd card. You are randomly generating a card and checking if it's already in the deck. The odds of getting a unique card is 1/52. For the 51st card, the odds are 2/52, and so on. So, you are doing unnecessary countless iterations to randomly generate last few cards. In fact, after the 19th card or so, the probability of repeating a card goes very high. Hence, std::shuffle is your friend.

Also for the `it stops at some point during the generation of the cards`, refer to @Stephan Lechner 's comment.

> Once duplicateCard has somewhere become true, it will never get false again. Then while (duplicateCard == true) will be an endless loop

Comment: This is known as the Fisher-Yates Shuffle. A good example of applying this approach can be found in [the example code for `std::iota` at cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/iota)

Comment: I did not know there was a name for it. Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 1):

Since the question is marked `c++`, I would like point out that the OP's example code is using old C coding style.

Some notes:

- Use `enums` over plain `std::string`'s

  - The **value** and **suit** of a card is *finite*, therefore use a finite `enum`.
- Use `std::vector`/`std::array` instead of C-style arrays
- Use the `algorithm` library of STL
- Use `static constexpr` variables for constants instead of magic numbers
- Make use of C++ `operator overloading`

Considering these notes and using `c++11` features, you could rewrite your code like this:

`Value`

```
enum class Value : int8_t
{
    None = -1,
    Two,
    Three,
    Four,
    Five,
    Six,
    Seven,
    Eight,
    Nine,
    Ten,
    Jack,
    Queen,
    King,
    Ace
};
```

Same goes for `Suit`

```
enum class Suit : int8_t
{
    None = -1,
    Heart,
    Diamond,
    Spade,
    Club
};
```

Now you can define a function to return a string representation

```
template<typename T>
std::string to_string(const T&);

template<>
std::string to_string<Value>(const Value& value)
{
    std::string str;
    switch(value)
    {
    case Value::None:  str = "None"; break;
    case Value::Two:   str = "2"; break;
    case Value::Three: str = "3"; break;
    case Value::Four:  str = "4"; break;
    case Value::Five:  str = "5"; break;
    case Value::Six:   str = "6"; break;
    case Value::Seven: str = "7"; break;
    case Value::Eight: str = "8"; break;
    case Value::Nine:  str = "9"; break;
    case Value::Ten:   str = "T"; break;
    case Value::Jack:  str = "J"; break;
    case Value::Queen: str = "Q"; break;
    case Value::King:  str = "K"; break;
    case Value::Ace:   str = "A"; break;

    default: break;
    }
    return str;
}

template<>
std::string to_string<Suit>(const Suit& suit)
{
    std::string str;
    switch(suit)
    {
    case Suit::None:    str = "None"; break;
    case Suit::Heart:   str = "h"; break;
    case Suit::Diamond: str = "d"; break;
    case Suit::Spade:   str = "s"; break;
    case Suit::Club:    str = "c"; break;
    default: break;
    }

    return str;
}
```

Define your constants (in a namespace)

```
namespace constants
{
static constexpr const size_t num_values = 13;
static constexpr const size_t num_suits  = 4;
static constexpr const size_t num_cards  = num_values * num_suits;
}
```

Now your `Card` class can look like this

```
class Card
{
public:

    constexpr Card() = default;
    constexpr Card(Value value, Suit suit) : m_value(value), m_suit(suit) {}

    Value  value()  const noexcept { return m_value; }
    Suit   suit()   const noexcept { return m_suit;  }

    Card& operator++() // 
    {
        if(m_value == Value::Ace)
            m_suit  = static_cast<Suit>((static_cast<int8_t>(m_suit) + 1) % constants::num_suits);

        m_value = static_cast<Value>((static_cast<int8_t>(m_value) + 1) % constants::num_values);
        return *this;
    }
    Card  operator++(int)
    {
        Card result(*this);
        ++(*this);
        return result;
    }

private:
    Value m_value{};
    Suit  m_suit{};

};

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Card& card)
{
    os << to_string(card.value()) << to_string(card.suit());
    return os;
}
```

The `operator++` overload is used later in the `Deck` class when initializing the `Deck` with `iota` (thanks to @user4581301).

And finally your `Deck` class can look like this:

```
class Deck
{
public:
    using Type           = std::array<Card, constants::num_cards>;
    using iterator       = Type::iterator;
    using const_iterator = Type::const_iterator;

    iterator       begin()       noexcept { return m_deck.begin(); }
    const_iterator begin() const noexcept { return m_deck.begin(); }
    iterator       end()         noexcept { return m_deck.end();   }
    const_iterator end()   const noexcept { return m_deck.end();   }

    void init()
    {
        std::iota(m_deck.begin(), m_deck.end(), Card(Value::Two, Suit::Heart));
    }

    void randomInit()
    {
        init();
        std::shuffle(m_deck.begin(), m_deck.end(), m_g);
    }

private:

    Type m_deck;
    std::random_device m_rd;
    std::mt19937 m_g{m_rd()};
};


std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Deck& deck)
{
    for(const auto& card : deck)
        os << card << ' ';

    return os;
}
```

To test `Deck::randomInit()`

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    Deck deck;

    deck.randomInit();
    std::cout << deck << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://ideone.com/lxBLh2)**

Answer (score 0):

You could generate your deck via nested for loops. Here is an approximation.

```
auto p = 0; // Deck position
for(auto i = 0; i < 13; i++) { // values
      for(auto j = 0; j < 4;  j++) {  // suits
          deck[p++] = /*Call constructor here.*/
      }
}
```

Afterwards, you can do what @Sahil said.

EDIT:

I forgot to specify that this only works with an enum. Otherwise it will be difficult to map the integers to the strings.